# How to remove Server header with kong response-transformer plugin?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I'm trying to remove the Server header by using the following declarative map in a serverless approach:

```
plugins:
  - name: response-transformer
    service: my-service
    config:
      remove.headers: Server
```

but I get:

```
in 'plugins':
 - in entry 1 of 'plugins':
in 'config':
  in 'remove.headers': unknown field
```

I also tried to override the value but it just seems that the above configuration has something missing...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is like this

```
- name: response-transformer
    service: my-service
    config:
      remove:
        headers: ["Server","Via"]
```

Comment: This does not remove the "Via" header.

Comment: These headers are injected by Kong post the execution of this plugin, so it won't remove those headers

Comment: @deadzg_devil thank you for this. I've been spinning in circles wondering why the plugin wasn't working. But it was working the entire time it seems

Comment: can you pls tell me which file should be edited with this ? I'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

The following kong configuration can be used to get rid of the "Via" header:

```
- name: KONG_HEADERS
  value: "off"
```

This removes the kong related headers. However, this doesn't seem to remove the "Server" header.

Comment: This seems to remove the `Server` header as well

Answer (score 0):

Based on the type of deployment turn the headers off using
`KONG_HEADERS: off`

You can also selectively remove the headers.

List of all the Kong headers injected:
https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.3.x/configuration/#headers